# fs.createWriteStream - download and merge multiple file segments into single one

Tags: javascript, node.js, netflix

I'm trying to use nodejs to create a single file from multiple fragments of an `octet/stream`. I'm using puppeteer to intercept requests and add each url like this one `https://ipv4-c003-nap002-teleit-isp.1.oca.nflxvideo.net/...` to an array. The urls in question points to small parts of a video file that is displayed using blob url in browser. Since I'm not so experienced with nodejs, I would ask if is possible to use the `fs.createWriteStream()` and `https.get()` functions to create a single file from those urls. Anyone can give me a suggestion about? After the file is downloaded, what is the correct file extension for an octet stream?